# Android AlertDialog with custom width

Tags: android, dialog, width

I know the answer to this question must be around somewhere, but I haven't been able to find it...

I have a custom AlertDialog, and no matter what parameters I set in the XML file and/or on the Java code, the dialog always shows with full screen width.

Right now, my layout file is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/color_picker_dlg_root"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TableRow>
[...]
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

and I create the AlertDialog in code like this:

```
layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.color_picker_dlg, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.color_picker_dlg_root));
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setView(layout);
[...]
dialog = builder.create();
```

... and the dialog still takes up all the screen width.

What can I do to make it wrap its content?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my dialogs. To cure it I had to set my dialogs with the dialog theme. Not sure how to do it with alert dialog but heres the code for a regular dialog.

```
    dialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.CustomDialog);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_custom_blank);
    dialog.setCancelable(isCancelable);
```

And here is the CustomDialog theme

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CustomDialog" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">

      <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
      <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
      <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
      <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>

    </style>

</resources>
```

If you would treally like to get into dialogs and create your own custom reusable dialog than check out the tutorial on my website

http://www.androidianlabs.com/custom-android-dialogs.html